# Los elementos de la fila siguiente quedan apegados a la fila anterior¿Como solucionarlo?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Estoy mostrando los productos almacenados en mi base de datos(para lo cual estoy utilizando laravel 5.6). Sin embargo al pasar a la siguiente linea horizontal, los productos quedan muy apegados a la linea anterior. ¿Como podría hacer que quedase un espaciado entre una linea de elementos y la siguiente? Les dejo una imagen para que se entienda mejor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="row">
  <!-- Menu Vertical, Filtros-->
  <div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="list-group border-0 card text-center text-md-left">
     <a href="#menu1" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Categoría</a>
      <div class="collapse" id="menu1" data-parent="#sidebar">
       <a href="#menu1sub1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Subitem 1 </a>
       <a href="#menu1sub2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Subitem 2</a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Subitem 3</a></div>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed"><i class="fa fa-film"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 2</span></a>
       <a href="#menu3" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 3 </span></a>
       <div class="collapse" id="menu3" data-parent="#sidebar">
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu3">3.1</a>
       <a href="#menu3sub2" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">3.2 </a>
       <div class="collapse" id="menu3sub2">
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu3sub2">3.2 a</a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu3sub2">3.2 b</a>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu3sub2">3.2 c</a>
       </div>
       <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#menu3">3.3</a>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
  <!-- Fin Menu Vertical, Filtros-->
  <!-- Lista de productos, cuatro filas -->
  <div class="col-md-9">
    @foreach($products->chunk(4) as $productChunk)
    <div class="row">
      @foreach($productChunk as $product)
      <div class="col-md-3">
       <div>
         <img src="{{ $product->imagePath  }}" class="img-thumbnail" style="max-height:249px;">
         <div class="caption">
           <h5 class="fb-responsive">{{ $product->name }}</h5>
           <p>$ {{ $product->price }}</p>
           <div>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="width:100%;">Agregar a tu Compra</button>
         </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      @endforeach
    </div>
    @endforeach

  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Fin de Lista de productos, cuatro filas -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: y por que no los dejas como cards?

Comment: Añade un style y ponle .row{ margin-bottom: 15px !important; }

Comment: simplemente añades a la clase `mb-3` y listo eso separará lo que quieres.

Comment: Gracias, no conocía esa clase, me sirvió. ¿Podrías colocarlo como respuesta para aceptarla? @SebastiánLagosYañez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de siguiente manera solo añadiendo la clase `mb-3`, que quiere decir esto?, Significa haz `Margin bottom`
Ejemplo

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    
    <div class="card mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Eso hace que se separen en la parte de abajo, pero para dejar mas claro mas adelante si quieres hacer margins, bootstrap es muy intuitivo, solo ponte a pensar como lo abreviaras: Por ejemplo `margin top` simplemente sigues la lógica

`mt-3`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    
    <div class="card mt-5" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card mt-2" style="width: 18rem;">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">

        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Fíjate , así mismo con los demás tanto con `padding` como con `marging`. Solo lo quería explicar para que quedara claro.

Comment: Tambien es bueno sugerir que manejes los estilos aparte y los agregues asi como agregas bootstrap para que mantengas tu codigo limpio y no lo mezcles con html